# Select first option from angular 'ng-model' select element , with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I can't find a way to select the first item in my array song by clicking on the button below

my code :

```
  <div class="list-group-item">
         <p>
            Titel : <select ng-model="selectedSong" ng-options="song as song.title for song in songs.tracks"></select>
         </p>
         <p>
            Artiest : <select ng-model="selectedSong" ng-options="song as song.artist.name for song in songs.tracks"></select>
         </p>
         <p>
            Tijdstip : <select ng-model="selectedSong" ng-options="song as song.played_at for song in songs.tracks"></select>
         </p>
         <!-- <button ng-click="selectedSong.value == '1'"></button> -->
  </div>
```

I left out my other code to make it clear . At this point when i select something in my  dropdownlist it is viewing elements below by using the ng-model directive. In the comments i tried to fix this with the ng-click directive on a button , but i see that this is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your click event you have to set `selectedSong` to the first `song`

```
<button ng-click="selectedSong = songs.tracks[0]"></button>
```

If you want to make sure you have songs in your `tracks` list you can do the following instead:

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="getFirstSong()"></button>
```

AngularJS (in your controller):

```
$scope.getFirstSong() = function () {
    if ($scope.songs.tracks.length > 0) {
        $scope.selectedSong = songs.tracks[0];
    }
};
```

Comment: you are my hero of the day !